# Ethers.js Batch Fetch Archive Transactions by Hash

Tags: ethers.js, alchemy, history, archive-node

I have a big array of emitted events that I retrieved using an archive node with Ethers `queryFilter`. I want to get the transaction parameters for each of those transactions.

I am using Ethers.js `await provider.getTransaction(txHash);` and passing a transaction hash which I have from my event data. Getting these one at a time from the archive node (Alchemy provider) is super slow and feels wrong.

Is there a way to batch fetch by passing say 1000s of transaction hashes at a time? Thinking it would be great to do this in the same way I batch fetch the events using an Ethers `queryFilter`.

Answer (score 0):

Could not find a way to do it with Ethers.js.

According to Alchemy docs you can do up to 1000 calls in a batch. https://docs.alchemy.com/reference/batch-requests

Used [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch) to build the Alchemy docs HTTP example in JS. This sped things up!

```js
import fetch from 'node-fetch';

async function alchemyProviderBatch(method, param2dArray, alchemyProviderUrl) {
  if (param2dArray.length > 1000) {
    throw Error('Alchemy provider can only do batches of 1000 or fewer.');
  }

  const postBody = [];
  param2dArray.forEach((params, i) => {
    postBody.push({
      jsonrpc: "2.0",
      id: i,
      method, // "eth_getTransactionByHash"
      params, // [ "0xtransaction_hash" ]
    });
  });

  const response = await fetch(alchemyProviderUrl, {
    method: 'post',
    body: JSON.stringify(postBody),
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
  });
  
  const data = await response.json();
  return data;
}
```